# Strong Params issue at new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, strong-parameters

I have `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` when I press create in my form.

In my controller:

```
 def create
      @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
      if @topic.save
         redirect_to topics_path, notice: 'Topic was successfully created.'
      else
         render action: 'new'
      end
 end
 def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :published, :title)
 end
```

In the view

```
    <%= f.input :title, label: 'Topic Name' , label_html: { class: "col-sm-4" } ,input_html: { class: 'col-sm-2 form-control' }, required: true %>
```

This is the log:
Requested Params are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uB3l+soqgt0qDX8JakSAPeBukp6oifViaHuxDxE9n/I=", "topic"=>{"title"=>"Selling2"}, "commit"=>"Update Page", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"topics"}
```

When I edit an already made topic, I don't get any errors just when I try to create a new one.

Thanks

Comment: This alone won't cause that error, do you have any kind of before filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Logan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29595/logan-serman).

I have had a filter at the top of my controller `filter_resource_access`. I remove that and all are good.

Anyway, not sure why it happens with `filter_resource_access` but that is another topic.

Cheers and thank you Logan.